# Side-aligned tabs in tabcontrol

Tags: c#, winforms, draw, tabcontrol

Since I'm a C# beginner I don't know what's to do in my case. I wanted a side-aligned tab control so I have found this:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Now the tabpage names are not getting displayed at all. How do I "draw" them? I hope someone can help me. The DrawItem method:

```
 private void tabControl1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Brush _textBrush;

        // Get the item from the collection.
        TabPage _tabPage = tabControl1.TabPages[e.Index];

        // Get the real bounds for the tab rectangle.
        Rectangle _tabBounds = tabControl1.GetTabRect(e.Index);

        if (e.State == DrawItemState.Selected)
        {

            // Draw a different background color, and don't paint a focus rectangle.
            _textBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Red);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Gray, e.Bounds);
        }
        else
        {
            _textBrush = new System.Drawing.SolidBrush(e.ForeColor);
            e.DrawBackground();
        }

        // Use our own font.
        Font _tabFont = new Font("Arial", (float)10.0, FontStyle.Bold, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

        // Draw string. Center the text.
        StringFormat _stringFlags = new StringFormat();
        _stringFlags.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        _stringFlags.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
        g.DrawString(_tabPage.Text, _tabFont, _textBrush, _tabBounds, new StringFormat(_stringFlags));
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the `g.DrawString` part in your current code?

Comment: Yes I have but I don't know how to use it correctly. That's my problem. Sorry if this is a silly question but I'm still learning the language.

Comment: That's alright, we've all been there! Could you edit your question to include your current `DrawItem` method?

Comment: Ok done! It's edited now

Comment: Is `_tabPage.Text` empty?

Comment: Ok now it seems to work! It was my fault. There was an error with my tab what I have fixed now. I think the question can be deleted/closed. Sorry for that and thanks for your help!

Comment: Great! [You can answer your own question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it when you can.